# Is an open connected subspace of $\mathbb{R^2}$ locally path-connected?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness, path-connected, locally-connected

I want to proof the following statement :

Let X be an open connected subspace of $\mathbb{R^2}$. Show that X is also path connected. The standard way to prove this problem from what I at least saw was to notice that a connected topological space has only two clopen subsets, namely X and the empty set. So if we define A as $A:=\{y\in X : \exists f: [0,1] \rightarrow X , f(0)=x, f(1)=y, \mbox{ f is continuous  }\}$, the set which consists of points path connected with x. We can show that A is clopen and then A must equal X. I want to proof if it in an alternative way and for that I mainly use Munkres Theorem 25.5 :

> Theorem 25.5:
> If X is a topological space, each path component of X lies in a component of X. If X is locally path connected, then the components and the path components are the same.

If X is connected, then it has only one component. If I can show it is locally path connected then using this theorem we find that X has only one path component; X itself which means it is path connected. So far this is what I got :

Let $x\in X$ with X an open connected subspace of $\mathbb{R^2}$:
An open neighbourhood of X is also an open neighbourhood of $\mathbb{R^2}$(by lemma 16.2). X is locally path connected at x if for every neighbourhood U there exists an open neighbourhood V such that V is path connected. Given any open neighbourhood of x , U, there exists $r>0$ such that V=$B_r(x)$, the open ball centered around x with radius r, is an open neighbourhood and V is a subset of U. An open ball in $\mathbb{R^2}$ is a circle which is convex and thus is path connected. We can do this in a similar fashion for all $x\in X$. Can we conclude that X is locally path connected? If not where is the fallacy in my argument? I would appreciate a hint or any kind of help.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen yeah my bad fixed it

Comment: Your proof is fine. Note that $X$ open is sufficient ($X$ connected is useless).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thx. I want to use the fact that X is connected to prove that X is path connected with theorem 25.5 as I pointed out.

Comment: What I mean is that in your last paragraph, you proved  that every open subset $X$ of $\Bbb R^2$ is locally path-connected, assuming uselessely that $X$ is connected.

Comment: This is a matter of taste, but mentioning local connectedness feels like overkill. If $X$ is non-empty and open, we can fix a point $x$ of $X$ arbitrarily and consider the sets $U_x$ of points in $X$ that _can_ be joined to $x$ by a path (or even a finite chain of horizontal and vertical line segments contained in $X$), and the set $V_x$ of points that _cannot_ be so joined to $x$. An elementary argument about disks shows that if $y\in U_x$, then some open disk about $y$ is contained in $U_x$, and similarly (contrapositively) if $y\in V_x$. Finally, $U_x$ and $V_x$ are disjoint by definition.